# TypeORM как использовать пагинацию в QueryBuilder

Tags: sql-server, nestjs, typeorm

- БД: MS SQL
- typeorm: ^0.2.34
- Back: NestJS

У меня был запрос через `find` с пагинацией, который работал как надо:

```
const data = await this.docRepository.find({
  relations: ['user', 'user.project'],
  skip: limit * (page - 1),
  take: limit,
  order: {
    create_at: 'DESC'
  }
})
```

но была необходимость сделать `orderBy` по полю из `relations` (`'user.project.creat_at': 'DESC'`) и как я выяснил через `find` это сделать невозможно. Поэтому я написал тот же запрос через `QueryBuilder`:

```
const data = await this.docRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('doc')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('doc.user', 'user')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('user.project', 'project')
  .orderBy({
    'doc.create_at': 'DESC',
    'project.create_at': 'DESC'
  })
  .limit(limit * (page - 1))
  .offset(limit)
  .getMany()
```

И тут проблема именно с пагинацией, если `find` сначала подготавливает результат вместе с `relations` а уже потом применяет разбиение на страницы, то `QueryBuilder` такого не делает и если в запросе есть `leftJoinAndSelect`, то он не будет сначала группировать связи а сразу обрежет результат, что является проблемой.

Подскажите, как решить вопрос с пагинацией на уровне SQL-запроса? Либо есть какие-то отдельные инструменты для этого?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант методом JS есть такое решение, может кому пригодиться:

```
const dataAll = await this.docRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('doc')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('doc.user', 'user')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('user.project', 'project')
  .orderBy({
    'doc.create_at': 'DESC',
    'project.create_at': 'DESC'
  })
  .getMany()

const data = dataAll.slice((limit * (page - 1)), (limit * page))
```

Answer (score 0):

[Пример из документации](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/using-pagination) с переводом

Применение пагинации:

```js
const users = await getRepository(User)
    .createQueryBuilder("user")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("user.photos", "photo")
    .skip(5)
    .take(10)
    .getMany();
```

Этот запрос пропустит первых 5 пользователей `(.skip(5))` и получит следующие 10 за ними `(.take(10))`